# Frag the "lag" tag

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags

The [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) tag (on 30 questions) seems awful.  In common parlance "lag" is a catch-all term for poor performance; attributable to myriad things.  Many of the questions it's on have a network bent, but several seem to be just about a local slowdown (graphics card/CPU overload, slow input)

(Right now [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) is a synonym of [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag), which in retrospect is probably a bad/fruitless idea)

Should we axe the tag and retag some of the questions with perhaps [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking) (or similar) or [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues)/[graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card)/[performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) (look, more catch-all tags `:\`)

---

Incorporating badp's suggestion:

1. remove synonym from [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) to [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag)
2. create synonym from [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) to [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency)
3. rename [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) to [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency)
4. create synonym from [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) to [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) (the new dumpster)

   - Maybe add to the [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) tag wiki summary something like:

     > If this is about a network related problem, consider using [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) or [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking), or for poor machine performance, [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)
5. manually go through [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) questions and retag the non-network related ones (8-10 of 30) to [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) or [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) as appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I would think that most networking issues should probably go to Super User, but I'm all for replacing the lag tag with it when it's definitely a networking issue.  I agree that [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) and [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) aren't helpful — a high ping is a symptom, not a problem, and not helpful as a tag.

[technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) seems too broad.  I suppose the question is whether people often use `[game-name] [technical-issues]` to search for problems they have.  [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance) is the same.

[graphics-card](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/graphics-card) has about 30% questions closed, not a good indicator, and I don't think it's a useful tag.  Shopping questions and comparisons are two common question types in that tag.  Some need more specific tags, like [vsync](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vsync) or something.  We have far too many "What should I consider?" questions that should be closed in favor of a single, canonical one.  I've voted to close a bunch.

Comment: This isn't a panacea for bad tags, just a step in a cleaner direction though.  I agree that `[tech-issues]` is also bad, but it's knowingly vague.  What are your thoughts on my concrete proposal?

Comment: @NickT Definitely a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag)is misused. No, I don't think [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag)should go away. Questions likes [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/49370/does-ping-matter-much-under-30ms) or [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39343/is-lag-compensation-affecting-my-performance) or [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/1241/what-is-lag-compensation) are fine and their tagging is just right.

So here's a counterproposal:

1. I mass-retag [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) to the more technical and less-known term [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) *without* creating an automatic redirection from [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) to [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency). This kills [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) and prevents automatic misuse of [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency). I also kill the synonym from [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) to [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag).
2. We go through all of these questions and remove [latency](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/latency) from questions that just ask about performance issues in general.

I'm open to creating, after the fact, a synonym from [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping)and [lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) to [technical-issues](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/technical-issues) or [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance), given that 'lag' is just that generic. Lag's not necessarily about networking: there's input lag and display lag and whatnot. My hard drive makes me lag all the time in TF2. >:(

Answer (score 2):

[lag](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/lag) has long-since been removed, and today I removed the [ping](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ping) synonym which was still in place. Moving forward:

- For general questions about Networks, use [networking](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/networking)
- For performance related questions, use [performance](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/performance)

Comment: Isn't it misleading to have the tag [tag:network-performance] as a synonym of the much broader tag [tag:performance], though?

Comment: @Joachim - The performance tag's description calls out network performance as being covered by it. It could be worth splitting out I guess, but that's how the tags are currently used. In the meantime what that synonym achieves is if someone starts typing "network" in the tag box, they will get tag suggestions for both [networking] and [performance] tags.